# Multi-country and multi-language website

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, multi-sites

I’m trying to create a Drupal 8 website with multi-country selection and more languages available for each Country. For example, the visitor can select Belgium as his Country, then he should be able to select one of the languages related to Belgium: French and German, plus English (which should be available for all Countries). I’ve installed two modules: Domain Access and Country Path. Domain Access allow me to define different domains and sub-domains like fr.domain.com, it.domain.com, etc. Using Country Path I should be able to **create different path for the same domain based on Country selection**, like domain.com/france, domain.com/italy etc. But unfortunately it’s not working properly… Using sub-domains is not possible for my project and, even configuring Country Path, if I go to domain.com/france I always get a page not found error.

What I need in the end is this path/url structure: **domain/country/language**, like for example *domain.com/belgium/fr* or *domain.com/belgium/en*. Do you had any experience with this situation? Any idea or suggestion about modules to try or core configurations that can solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The purpose of the site is not giving ideas, suggestions, or hints; it's answering an on-topic question with a definitive, objective answer. Recommendations for modules are off-topic for us.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks you for the clarification. Of course I really hope to get a definitive and objective answer to my question from someone who already obtained a good solution for my needing. Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: @Gabriele, did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @Vinoth We managed it by creating several subdomains like it.domain.com, de.domain.com etc. associated to different Domains Records (Domain Access module). We have installed all the needed language translations and created a custom module to manage the associations between the domain and the available languages. Using the Domain Access module you also get the list of available domains (countries) in the user profile edit form. Hope this can help.